# Create a summary table by group from a dataset with 30 columns in R

Tags: r

consider I have this sample data:

```
ID <- c(1:10)
group <- c("A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B")
condition_tall <- c(0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1)
condition_long <- c(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1)
condition_wide <- c(1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0)
check_tall <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1)
check_long <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1)
check_wide <- c(1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1)

dat <- data.frame(ID,group,condition_tall,condition_long,condition_wide,check_tall,check_long,check_wide)
dat
```

What would the most efficient way bet o generate a summary table like this in R? I want the counts and percentages by group, for "condition" and "check." Thank you so much.

|  | Group A |  |  |  | Group B |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Variable | Condition (N) | Condition (%) | Check (N) | Check (%) | Condition (N) | Condition (%) | Check (N) | Check (%) |  |
| tall |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| long |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| wide |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Answer (score 2):

```
dat %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(across(-ID, list(n=sum, pct=mean))) %>%
  pivot_longer(-group, c('name', 'var', 'name1'),names_sep = '_') %>%
  pivot_wider(var, names_from = c(group, name, name1))
```

results

```
# A tibble: 3 x 9
  var   A_condition_n A_condition_pct A_check_n A_check_pct B_condition_n B_condition_pct B_check_n B_check_pct
  <chr>         <dbl>           <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>         <dbl>           <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>
1 tall              2           0.667         3       1                 4           0.571         5       0.714
2 long              3           1             3       1                 4           0.571         5       0.714
3 wide              2           0.667         2       0.667             4           0.571         4       0.571
```

Another quick way:

```
fn <- ~list(c(n=sum(.x),pct=mean(.x)))

dat %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(ID, group), c('name1', 'var'), names_sep = '_') %>%
  pivot_wider(var, names_from = c(group, name1), values_fn = fn) %>%
  unnest_wider(-var, names_sep = '_')
```

Results:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 9
  var   A_condition_n A_condition_pct A_check_n A_check_pct B_condition_n B_condition_pct B_check_n B_check_pct
  <chr>         <dbl>           <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>         <dbl>           <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>
1 tall              2           0.667         3       1                 4           0.571         5       0.714
2 long              3           1             3       1                 4           0.571         5       0.714
3 wide              2           0.667         2       0.667             4           0.571         4       0.571
```